# How can we add the values inside a tab which is in each loop?

Tags: cypress

I need to valuate the 1st tab value is equal to the total values of other tabs
For eg: 1st tab has 12
2nd , 3rd and 4th tab has 1,5,2,4 respectively.
The tabs can be increase since it is dynamic.
But the 1st tab value should match the other tabs total count.

Comment: Please add a minimal reproducible example to your question. If code is proprietary, please show a representative equivalent HTML layout.

Comment: How can we add the values of a tabs which is dynamic?

Answer (score 1):

If you have this HTML

```html
<tab>
  <span>10</span>
</tab>
<tab>
  <span>6</span>
</tab>
<tab>
  <span>4</span>
</tab>
```

This will test the first equals the rest (any number of tabs)

```js
cy.get('tab')
  .find('span')
  .then($spans => {
    return [...$spans].map(span => +span.innerText) // extract values
  })
  .should(values => {
    const allValue = values[0]
    const rest = values.slice(1)           // 2nd val onwards
      .reduce((sum, val) => sum + val, 0)  // sum them
 
    expect(allValue).to.eq(rest)
  })
```

[image]

Comment: Getting cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'reduce')

Comment: It works for me. What's different on your end?

Comment: I'm getting error like expected 10 to equal NaN.

Comment: What's different in the page layout?

Comment: There are four categories in a page , which has names like All , Selected and other two tabs .. there are a values inside the each category for eg: All has 11 , selected( can be ignored) and other categories has 1 and 10 respectively. Need to validate 11 ( All category) is equal to sum of other tabs ie 1 and 10.

Comment: Because of `NaN` in the message, I think there's some other `<span>` being picked up, so your HTML is more complicated than the example I gave. What does it look like?

Comment: Ok. There is a div class , inside it has a span class with value. I need to get that and do the sum for rest tabs. Please suggest your thoughts on this.

Comment: @KishoreD please give your exact HTML in the initial question

Comment: Really sorry , I couldn't give it due to privacy policy of my organization. It's a client data

Answer (score 0):

Assuming that the number is coming as innerText, you can do this:

```js
cy.get('tab1').invoke('text').then((tab1) => {
  cy.get('tab2').invoke('text').then((tab2) => {
    const total = +tab1 + +tab2
    cy.get('alltab').should('have.text', total.toString())
  })
})
```

Comment: The number is coming from a span class. How can I verify the value from a span class and the calculation

Comment: Please add the html showing the numbers.

Comment: The above code is working. But there is one catch , I need to ignore the 2nd tab and only need to add the remaining tabs which is available. Can you suggest how  to write this.